# Imported a SQL Server database, and it says login failed for a user that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a asp.net web application that I was hosting somewhere.

I backed up the database and restored it locally.

Now when I run the application, it says `myapp_user123011` doesn't exist.

When looking at the security section for the db and the database server, I don't see that user anywhere.

My `web.config` was changed to use the `sa` account.

Not sure where this user could be referenced?

I'm guessing this database user was imported into my database server (SQL Server 2008 R2) but for some reason isn't showing up in the user list in the security sections).

How can I search and delete this user if this is the case?

(Note: I have searched the entire solution for that username and it doesn't exist)

Comment: You should **NEVER EVER** use the `sa` account from an application...

Comment: In server management studio, find your database and expand the node users. There you will propably see myapp_user123011. Most likely does not have a login to the database. Easiest is propably to create a new user.

Comment: @MikaelHärsjö I checked there, it isn't in security|users node, nor is it in security|logins node.

Comment: @Marc_s it is just local development, what's the big deal?

Comment: What do you mean "it says"? What is "it"? Check the SQL Server error log and see where the error is coming from. You should also search your source code on the machine (not through Visual Studio) for myapp_user123011 - that's obviously coming from your app, is this happening when you run the app or when you debug the app from Visual Studio?

Comment: The reason it's a big deal, is that sa has a lot more privilege than your average user. So if you develop locally with SA, when you deploy the app and use a normal user, stuff might start to break because your normal user doesn't have the same level of rights. Principal of least privilege!

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm testing locally, and in debug mode currently.  I'm tracing through it now to see the connection string while it runs thanks.

Comment: ok I was actually viewing the live server which I changed the pwd too.

Comment: The risk is that you happen to forget to change this and suddenly you have a live production site using the `sa` account.... and the `sa` account can do **anything** on your SQL Server - so good luck with those script kiddies hacking into your SQL injection holes and taking over your production SQL Server.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Silly me, my local website was redirecting to the live site when I clicked on a link which was hitting the db.  And I had changed the password on the live server during the backup.

Comment: This is a big deal.  You hooked up an application under development to a production database.  By a fortunate mistake you didn't make changes to your production database.

Comment: no, I clicked on a link which WENT to the live site (I thought I was still on localhost).

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server there are two "users"

- A Database login which is at the server level (SQL Login)
- A Database user which is at the database level

These are connected.

When you move a database between servers you need to create the sql login and connect them to the database users.

Comment: I created a new user, still seeing the same error for that user that was at my hosting company.

Comment: could you post the full text of your error and your connection string (minus password)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some part of your code is connecting to DB using integrated authentication and your app is running under application pool which is using myapp_user123011 user credentials?

Comment: no, that user was on hosting companies server.